# Mostly pluses and minuses: says Grandpa

Tags: riddle

"You know, these little devils?" says Grandpa.

> "Billions of them. Everywhere. Here, outside! Very useful..."
>
> "...but their names get bad rap, you know", he sighed.
>
> "They are mostly pluses and minuses. Well, some are stars, squares and
> polygons too. And, son, they always need help to enter. Without help,
> they cannot do their job."

I knew what he was talking about. Nothing microscopic.

Who are they? Who helps them?

Comment: Is "[bad wrap](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/usage-bad-rap-vs-bad-rep-vs-bad-wrap)" intentional?

Comment: @CodeCaster That rocked my world. I thought "bad rap" was for having bad [rapport](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rapport)

Comment: The word "screw" has a bad meaning also

Comment: @DEEM ^^ rot13(Gur nafjre vf va cynva fvtug!)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think Grandpa is talking about

> Screws

And the shapes are

> The different shapes of the cavity on a screw head (Philips head is a plus, flat head is a minus. These are the most common but there are more unusual ones too)

They are helped to gain entry by

> Screwdrivers

Comment: And I think the "bad rap" refers to rot13(trggvat fperjrq).